# What is the definition of \abc in this case?

Tags: definition

When I compile the following code I get the error:

"use of \abc doesn't match its definition"

What is the definition of \abc?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\foo#1{\def\abc#1{test}}
\foo{gh}

\abc x y z

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! if you want `\abc` to have "its own" parameter, you can use `\def\abc##1{test}`. the double `#` is needed because `#1` is already "taken" as the 1st parameter of `\foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `\show\foo` and `\show\abc`. Then run LaTeX in interactive mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\foo#1{\def\abc#1{test}}
\foo{gh}

\show\foo
\show\abc

\abc x y z

\end{document}
```

TeX will stop like for an error and show

```
> \foo=macro:
#1->\def \abc #1{test}.
l.8 \show\foo
```

Hit return to see the next message

```
> \abc=macro:
gh->test.
l.9 \show\abc
```

Hit return again to get

```
! Use of \abc doesn't match its definition.
l.11 \abc x
            y z
```

<sup>If you can't run in interactive mode, say `\meaning\foo` instead and look at the generated output.</sup>

The format for `\show` when the token to be shown is a macro is

```
<parameter text>-><replacement text>.
```

(note the final period that's not part of the replacement text).

The parameter text in the case of `\foo` is `#1`, which means that TeX will look for an argument with the usual rules. Notice that the parameter text denotes something that TeX *must* find. For instance, if you call `{\foo}`, TeX will complain because it cannot find an argument: a closing brace is not  a suitable token to be taken as argument.

In the case of `\abc` what's shown as parameter text is `gh`, which means that after `\abc` TeX *must* find `gh`. If not, an error will be raised.

But you don't really need `\show`: just follow the expansion. The call

```
\foo{gh}
```

will result in TeX replacing `\foo` with its replacement text after looking for the arguments:

```
\def\abc gh{test}
```

Not `\def\abcgh` as you might expect. In the replacement text of `\foo`, `\abc` is a single token and TeX only processes tokens. So you get, with `•` for dividing tokens,

```
\def•\abc•g•h•{•t•e•s•t•}
```

The parameter text is anything that follows the macro to be defined up to the first `{`. It can contain `#` for denoting required arguments like in the case of `\foo`, but it needn't.

Comment: This answer is arguably better as it teaches OP how to debug the issue other than by staring at the code (and the latter doesn't always work). Nevertheless in this case it's a bit unclear what OP actually wants to get (`\abcgh` or `\abc ##1`? in the latter case what's the point of passing `#1` into `\foo` in the first place? Probably initially there wasn't but OP add that to temporarily "fix" the first error)

Comment: @user202729 Sorry, I cannot read minds. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`\def\abc gh{test}`

defines `\abc` to be a macro that must be followed by `gh` and expands to `test`, use as

```
\abc gh x y z
```